# Finding which MD algorithm to call EVP_verifyInit() with

Tags: hash, openssl, digital-signature

I am verifying a detached signature of some binary data using openssl C api, using EVP_verifyInit(), EVP_verifyUpdate() and EVP_verifyFinal().

The former needs a MD algorithm, which may in my situation be either SHA1, SHA256, etc. How do I figure out, from the signature binary data which MD algorithm to pass to EVP_verifyInit() ?

I haven't found any API function in openssl that seems to return this information.